# What is the equivalent of the --set functionality for helm install command, when using ansible community.kubernetes.helm plugin?

Tags: ansible, kubernetes-helm

I want to deploy helm chart using ansible-playbook,
my command looks like this:

helm install istio-operator manifests/charts/istio-operator --set operatorNamespace=istio-operator

however I could not find the equivalent for the --set arguments in the ansible plugin.

Comment: what word in your command shows you're using `ansible plugin`? i'm just curious

Comment: this is the original command (helm install istio-operator manifests/charts/istio-operator --set operatorNamespace=istio-operator) that I need to translate to a playbook command, using an ansible plugin "community.Kubernetes.helm"  however I don't know how to translate the --set part of the original command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad news is the documentation fails to document the `values:` parameter, but one can see its use [in the Examples section](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/community/kubernetes/helm_module.html#examples)

```yaml
- community.kubernetes.helm:
    name: istio-operator
    chart_ref: manifests/charts/istio-operator
    values:
      operatorNamespace: istio-operator
```

If for some reason that doesn't work, using `--set` is (plus or minus) the same as putting that key-value pair in a yaml file and then calling `--values $the_filename`, so you'd want to do that same operation only manually: create the file on the target machine (not the controller), then invoke `c...k...helm:` with [the documented `values_files:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/community/kubernetes/helm_module.html#parameter-values_files) pointed at that newly created yaml file